# Printing certain arrays

Tags: c, arrays

im trying to print and count a certain array from my table. i want to print 'O' and count how many times it pops up. The counting part i got it but to print the 'O' in a table format i cant. Everytime i would try to print the 'O' it gives me happy faces.

```
char poste[]={'A','P','A','P','A','O','P','P','O'};
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    if(poste[i]=='O') count++;
}

printf("Number of operators :%d\n", count);
printf("Poste\n");

for(i=0; i<9;i++)
{
    printf("%c",poste[i]=='O');
}
```

Execution gives me these happy faces

```
Poste   
A       
P       
A      
P      
A      
O       
P      
P       
O      
number of operators :2
Poste
☺  ☺
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing `poste[i]=='O'`.  What you want to do is as follows:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
    if ( poste[i] == 'O' )
        printf ( "%c", poste[i] );
```

Comment: thx, i totally forgot about the == signs mean true which is equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your line `printf("%c",poste[i]=='O')` is printing a character. Which character? Well, `poste[i]=='O'` is a condition. Conditions return `true` or `false`. When those values get converted into a character, they will first be converted to an int, `1` or `0`, and then a char, '☺' (which is the character with ascii value of 1) or 'null'.

What you want is to check the condition with an if statement and then printf the actual character:

```
if ( poste[i] == 'O' ) {
    printf ( "%c", poste[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%c",poste[i]=='O');
```

Here `poste[i] == 'O'`, this evaluates to either 1 (true, `poste[i]` is equal to `'O'`) or 0 (false, it isn't equal).

This result is of type `int`, but you're telling `printf` it is a `char`. Since `int`s and `char`s are not the same type and not equal in size this leads to weird and *undefined behaviour*. In this case the computer starts grinning like a madman.

If you want to print  1 or 0 to indicate equality change `%c` to `%i` (or `%d`). If you want to print an `'O'` everytime it is equal then change it to

```
if(poste[i] == 'O'){
    printf("%c", poste[i]);
}
```

note that, by then you might as well just print

```
printf("O");
```

since you know it will only print 'O's

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the result of the expression `poste[i]=='O'`.
Replace `printf("%c",poste[i]=='O');`
with `if (poste[i] == 'O') printf("O");`